# how to represent Updates avtivity using UML

Tags: uml

I am trying to create an activity diagram and i need to represent an update activity. So is it possible to do this in activity diagram or there is another alternatives to do so ???

thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by `update activity`?

Comment: i have a search class which get updated every 3 hours by a controller , that mean that the controller should make a research every time and if there's a change it should show the changes to the user .

Comment: Ok. But where is the problem then?

Comment: my probleme is how to represente that time (i mean every 3 hours ) in an activity diagram or if there's a better one that could do the job because i don't know all the diagrams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a receive event like this:

[image]

Probably you shouldn't bother with interruptible regions here.